# Is it possible to change file status (from read only to read and write) for multiple files/folders at once?

Tags: macbook-pro

I moved all my web files/folders from my default MAMP directory to a more manageable location. Now all the files and folders have been changed to read only.

I figured out how to change the status per one by one, but that would take a lot of time. Is there a way to change all the files and folders to "read and write" all at once

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Open terminal and try the following; putting the path of your new directory behind the /:

```
chmod -R o+rw /path/to/your/new/directory
```

-R means recursively change the permissions of all files in the directory, with the arguments ( o+rw ):

```
o ( the other users), alternatively u (for user) or g (for group)
r ( read )
w ( write )
```

Answer (score 0):

Better to just give the permissions you're looking for:

```
chmod -R g+w Music
```

-R -- recursive
g+w -- give write privileges to the group (which includes osx system-level users)
Music -- the relative (or /Music for an absolute) path to the new Folder.

Obviously, in case you didn't figure it out, you need to run this in Terminal.app